# How do I specify number of Hash iterations to be used in Apache Shiro?

Tags: hash, shiro

I'm working with a `JSF2` application where I'd like to use `Apache Shiro`. I have it up-and-running though I don't know how to specify the number of `Hash` iterations to be used.

**shiro.ini**

```
[main]

user = com.nivis.filter.FacesAjaxAwareUserFilter    
shiro.loginUrl = /faces/login.xhtml    
user.loginUrl = /faces/login.xhtml

jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true    
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM app_user WHERE username = ?  

dataSource = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory       
dataSource.requiredType = javax.sql.DataSource      
dataSource.resourceName = JNDImysql  

jdbcRealm.dataSource = $dataSource      
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm

passwordService = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService    
passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher    
passwordMatcher.passwordService = $passwordService

jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $passwordMatcher

[urls]  

/faces/login.xhtml = user      
/faces/index.xhtml = user      
/faces/app/** = user
```

It does work to get the password hashed even though I do not explicitly specify a `hash service`. I saw an example using:

```
hashService = org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.DefaultHashService
hashService.hashIterations = 10000
hashService.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
passwordService.hashService = $hashService
```

Which I tried to use, although it didn't make any difference. As it seems to be enough to use only the `PasswordService` to get the password hashed, I'd like to know if there's a way of specifying how many hash iterations to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to do it like this:

```
# Configure Data Source --> see web.xml for full configuration
dataSource = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
dataSource.resourceName = <resource name>
dataSource.resourceRef = true

# Create JDBC-Realm to connect to the Datasource and set the authenticationQuery
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $dataSource
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM <user table> WHERE email = ?

# Configure JDBC realm password hashing.
hashService = org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.DefaultHashService
hashService.hashIterations = <number of iterations>
hashService.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
hashService.generatePublicSalt = true
# privateSalt needs to be base64-encoded in shiro.ini but not in the Java code!
hashService.privateSalt = <base64-encoded Salt string>
passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher

passwordService = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
passwordService.hashService = $hashService
passwordMatcher.passwordService = $passwordService

jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $passwordMatcher
```

Note: this example also uses a private salt. To add more security against passwords being calculated using rainbow tables / brute force attacks, I strongly recommend using a salt. The above example code might not be the best way to handle salting, but it works fine. Also take care that a Salt needs to be base64-encoded in the shiro.ini but not in the java code.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. It works! Thank you : )